# Cocoapods RUBY undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

I am still quite a beginner on Ruby. I am trying to write some extra code to handle our 50 targets Cocoapods dependencies.

With the following code:

```
testString = "TEST!!!"

def processPods(platform_name)
    project = Xcodeproj::Project.open "./WhiteLabel.xcodeproj"
    project.targets.each { |target| 
        target_name = target.name
        if target.platform_name == platform_name
            puts "Processing #{target_name} for Platform #{platform_name}"
            puts testString #-->Error ...
        end 
    }
end

#Cocoapods methods
abstract_target 'iOS' do
    puts testString #-->Executes
    processPods(:ios)
end
```

For the sake of the question, "testString" replaces a bigger variable.

When I run the code I get:

```
TEST!!!
Processing WhiteLabel for Platform ios

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `testString' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007f8fe11cc2d0>.

 #  from ~/Documents/Developer/Xcode/WhiteLabelApple/Podfile:124
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #              puts "Processing #{target_name} for Platform #{platform_name}"
 >              puts testString
 #          end 
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that start with a lowercase letter are *local* variables. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in. (Hence why they are called "local" variables.)

In your case, you are defining a local variable named `testString` in the *script scope*, and are trying to access it in the scope of the method definition body `processPods`, where it simply isn't defined.

It works in the block at the bottom, because *block scopes* nest.

You can either:

- pass an additional argument to `processPods`,
- define the method using a block instead of a method definition expression, or
- make the variable a *constant variable* in the `Object` scope by changing its name to uppercase.

Comment: Yes, variable names that start with an uppercase letter are *constants*.

Comment: Great explanation! I just replaced the first Letter to uppercase and it worked. At least now I know more about ruby.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the variable name, you can take advantage of the fact that Ruby blocks are closures; the enclosing variables are accessible within the block.

```
test_string = "TEST!!!"

process_pods = lambda do |platform_name|
    project = Xcodeproj::Project.open "./WhiteLabel.xcodeproj"
    project.targets.each { |target| 
        target_name = target.name
        if target.platform_name == platform_name
            puts "Processing #{target_name} for Platform #{platform_name}"
            puts test_string #-->Should work ...
        end 
    }
end

abstract_target 'iOS' do
    puts test_string #-->Executes
    process_pods.call(:ios)
end
```

Sometimes, it's not possible to change the variable to a constant because it is in fact, variable. So putting code in a block provides a way to organize the code without sacrificing access to the surrounding variables.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am still quite new! In this case, it's a constant but I will keep that in mind!